# SSRS wrap text in Text Boxes

Tags: reporting-services, word-wrap

I have an SSRS report with a Text box that the user needs to enter notes into.  If the user types a super long sentence, the text extends beyond the edge of the page in MS Word.  I have set the property CanGrow to false.  Is there something that needs to be done to ensure the text wraps inside the text box?

Answer (score 1):

SSRS renders report data regions as a set of nested tables in Word, you can sometimes improve Word rendering layout by putting a Textbox inside another region e.g. a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

I set CanGrow = False and increased the size of the textbox to accommodate the text.  This, of course, will not likely work if you do not have the room to increase the size of the textbox.  That is what I will work on next. :(  My textbox is inside of a rectangle.